# Forcing Redirections for mobile devices?

Tags: redirect, mobile

I'm developing a website and we are building some pages for mobiles.

Should we force mobile users to go to the mobile site or present them with an option to select mobile or regular views.

I know that almost all mobile websites do not give you the opportunity to choose if you come up with a mobile device they just force you to mobile site.

What's the best practice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see how this is a programming related question, this is a marketting question. Programmers can give you as much input on this as can the average Joe.

Comment: I agree its not a technical question, however, this question has come up on every mobile website project I have worked on.

Comment: Thanks for your opinions guys but what you say does not help anyway ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MTDetect on your Desktop website.

Automatically redirect to your mobile website based on what devices/resolutions you want to service.

Provide a "Desktop" link on the mobile site to take users back to the Desktop website.

Alternatively, you can set up a mechanism on your Desktop to allow users to "subscribe" to the desktop website only using a cookie.  Your desktop code would look for the cookie, if it wasn't there then the MTDetect would fire and redirect to the mobile would ensue.

A more advanced approach is to build a Device Agnostic Responsive Layout that molds itself to the dimensions of the device/desktop browser.

Comment: The DARL is the ideal but some websites simply can't work like that. You know the saying, you can't please everyone in one go. :)

Answer (score 0):

The best option is for your mobile site to be designed explicitly for the mobile with no features missing. They should be equal, but the layout should be different, so that they will PREFER the mobile version on their phone and the pc version on their computer. Then it doesn't matter if you force them, they would pick mobile anyway.

Comment: I disagree. I think your regular website should be made using standard technologies that look great on modern mobile devices. (Unless you have to support really old or odd mobile devices, I guess.) There's nothing I hate more than going to a website on my computer, and later looking at it on my phone only to realize it's completely different.

Comment: But a lot of websites look and feel MUCH better on the phone in mobile mode, the buttons are larger and simple, and so much is changed it's pointless to re-use the same code base. The only problem people make when designing a mobile version is they forget features that are on the main version, but there's no reason to have to keep zooming in and getting confused using the pc version on a mobile, it's not designed for that kind of interface. I wouldn't use an XBOX controller to play the WII, the interfaces are simply too different.

Comment: I contend that if the website looks and feels much better on the phone in mobile mode then you've probably designed the regular version incorrectly. Most websites look and work great on my phone as-is, and the mobile versions - even the ones that vary only in layout - are far more confusing because I can't find anything because it's different from the regular website that I'm used to.

Comment: There's simply the case of resolution. A site catered to the small, touch screens of a mobile will look horrible in a full browser. I mean, the difference between facebook for Mobile and facebook for PC is staggering, but the Mobile version is ridiculously more fluid WHEN I'm on mobile, and the PC version is much nicer when I'm on PC. You've changed peripherals, from a mouse/keyboard to a finger. I mean, what if you wanted something like keyboard navigation? On a huge amount of phones, the keyboard takes up half the screen, so you have to re-design the navigation.. They're so different.